# Selenium find button element

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find a button element on a website with `selenium` on `python 3` . I try some different method but all failed . I use `Xpath` to find my element but i don't know if it's the better method :

This is the `HTML` code :

```
<div id="review-buttons-container">
<div class="columns">
<div class="please-wait" id="review-please-wait" style="display:none;">

<span>PROCESSING...</span>
</div>
<input id="place_order" type="button" value="Complete Order" class="button end"/>
</div>
</div>
```

This what i already try on python :

```
br.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='place_order']").click()
```

return :

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (606, 678). Other element would receive the click :
>
> ...

```
//div[@id='review-buttons-container']/div/input
```

return :

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='review-buttons-container']/div/input"}

```
br.find_element_by_xpath("//form[2]/div[8]/div/input").click()
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[2]/div[8]/div/input"}

Any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActionChains` to move to the element before clicking on it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = br.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='place_order']")
ActionChains(br).move_to_element(element).perform() # I assume br is your webdriver
element.click()
```

If you don't want to use `xpath` you can use `find_element_by_id('place_order')`

You can find [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) more ways to locate elements

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to scroll to this button before clicking using its location and js

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("place_order") 
element_position = element.location["y"] 
driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, {})".format(element_position))
time.sleep(1) #may not be required
element.click()
```